# Selecionar os dois maiores valores de um vetor e somá-los?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
atletas = []

while True:

    nome = input("Nome: ")

    if not nome: break

    saltos = []
    for i in range(3):
        salto = float(input("Distância {}: ".format(i+1)))
        saltos.append(salto)

    atletas.append({
        "nome": nome,
        "saltos": saltos
    })

for atleta in atletas:
    print("Nome:", atleta["nome"])
    print("Saltos:", atleta["saltos"])
    print("Média:", sum(atleta["saltos"])/3)
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Comece por fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) no site para perceber melhor como funciona. Depois evite fazer questões apenas com código. Tente detalhar ao máximo o seu problema para que fique claro para todos e seja facil de obter ajuda. Não hesite também em ver [como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode ordernar o seu vetor de forma decrescente usando o método `sort()` e passando o argumento `reverse=True`.

Uma vez ordenada de forma decrescente, você pode usar a função `sum()` para somar apenas os dois primeiros elementos do vetor, veja só:

```
vetor = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0 ]
vetor.sort(reverse=True)
print sum( vetor[:2] )
```

Saída:

```
17
```